# How do we have to retrieve data from excel using datadriver library

Tags: robotframework

I'm getting the following error:

> Calling method '_start_suite' of listener 'DataDriver' failed: FileNotFoundError: File attribute was not a full path

```
*** Settings ***

Library   Selenium2Library
Library     DataDriver      file=../TestData/LoginData.xlsx     sheet_name=2nd Sheet
```

Comment: At least for me, the error is self-explanatory - the library cannot find the file at the location you've specified.

Comment: i got the solution, thanks.

Comment: What is that, could you share, the solution here

Comment: i had given the wrong path